# Angular Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular8

I am getting the following: "Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorInterceptor: (?)" when trying to inject AuthenticationService.

**error.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import ...

import { AuthenticationService } from '@/_services';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

**authentication.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import ...

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public currentUser: Observable<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}

public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}

login(username, password) {
    ...
}

logout() {
    ...
}
}
```

**app.module.ts** contains:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

I am using Angular 8.
Full error code:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorInterceptor: (?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:2687)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:21355)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:21248)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (compiler.js:21470)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:21479)
at eval (compiler.js:21417)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:21377)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:21096)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:27143)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is circular dependency. `AuthenticationService` needs `HttpClient`, `HttpClient` needs `Interceptors`, `ErrorInterceptor` needs `AuthenticationService`.

In order to solve this, you need to separate `AuthenticationService` into two layers - one for storing the authentication data and one for the API communication.

```
class AuthenticationStore {
   storeData(authData) {}
   getData(): AuthData {}
   clearData() {}
```

Say you have the `AuthenticationStore`. Then the `ErrorInterceptor` would use the `AuthenticationStore` instead of `AuthenticationService`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationStore: AuthenticationStore) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationStore.clearData();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

Or you can use injector, that's a bit dirtier solution.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                const authenticationService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
                authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```